# Is this the correct way to use ConfigureAwait(false)?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I am building a WPF application and calling this custom event.
The question here is should I call `ConfigureAwait(false)` at everywhere? As you can see now that I am calling it 2 times. Or even 3 times in second approach with double `ConfigureAwait(false)` in the same line.

```
// First approach
void RaiseProcessEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(async () => await APIManager.GetInstance.ProcessMethod()).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

// Second approach
void RaiseProcessEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(async () => await APIManager.GetInstance.ProcessMethod().ConfigureAwait(false)).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

// This function is in a singleton class
public async Task ProcessMethod()
{
    var result = await GetInstance.GetFinalResultFromHttpClientAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);     
}
```

Comment: Can be a sticky subject, checkout [https://johnthiriet.com/configure-await/](https://johnthiriet.com/configure-await/) to see if that helps your scenario

Comment: yea, i read that before. Its abit of confusing and some or most websites says use "while your can" so i was just thinking just add in for the sake of adding.Personally,i don't feel any different

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The question here is should i call ConfigureAwait(false) at everywhere?

Generally speaking, [`ConfigureAwait(false)` should be used if the method does not need to resume on its calling context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). The decision of whether or not to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` should be made on a per-method basis, and should either be used for every `await` in that method, or it should not be used for every `await` in that method.

More pragmatically, `ConfigureAwait(false)` should be used in code that is intended for reuse, possibly in different contexts. Application code seldom needs to use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, although there have been situations I've encountered where it was necessary to [prevent having a bunch of continuations interrupting the UI thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/ui-guidelines-for-async.html).

> as you can see now that i am calling 2 time. or even 3 times in second approach with double configure(false) in the same line.

In those cases, the `ConfigureAwait(false)` is meaningless. Here's why:

```
//first approach
Task.Run(async () => await APIManager.GetInstance.ProcessMethod()).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

`ConfigureAwait` configures an `await`. It does not configure a task. Since the task returned from `Task.Run` is never `await`ed, this `ConfigureAwait` does nothing.

```
//second approach
Task.Run(async () => await APIManager.GetInstance.ProcessMethod().ConfigureAwait(false)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The `false` part of `ConfigureAwait(false)` is for the `continueOnCapturedContext` parameter. So `ConfigureAwait(false)` is saying "this method does not need to continue on the captured context". But in this case, the `async` delegate is being run on the thread pool (that's what `Task.Run` does), so you *know* that there's no context to capture anyway.

Side note 1: When using `Task.Run` to call an asynchronous method, it's common to [elide the `async` and `await` keywords](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html). E.g.: `Task.Run(() => APIManager.GetInstance.ProcessMethod());`. So the `ConfigureAwait(false)` question becomes moot anyway because there's no `await` anymore.

Side note 2: Discarding the task returned from `Task.Run` means that the code is doing fire-and-forget, which is almost always a terrible mistake. Among other things, this means that any exceptions are silently swallowed. It is almost always better to use `await`:

```
async void RaiseProcessEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Task.Run(() => APIManager.GetInstance.ProcessMethod());
}
```

Now there's an `await` for the task returned from `Task.Run`, so it's appropriate to ask the question at this point: should this `await` be using `ConfigureAwait(false)`? Opinions can vary here, but I would say no, because this is clearly application-level code (a UI event handler), and most developers would assume code running an event handler would be on the UI thread (even if there was an `await` previously in that method). So for maximum maintainability I would not use a `ConfigureAwait(false)` in a UI event handler method, unless I had to add it for performance reasons.

Comment: HI ,your explanation is very clear. yes,fire and throw is what i need as my ProcessMethod is calling a Httpclient which i have a try catch inside for logging purpose. SO i can safely remove that method after the task.run

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SO!

If you're writing application code then you probably shouldn't be using it at all. There's a big discussion about this in the [ConfigureAwait FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/) on MSDN.

TL;DR:

> use ConfigureAwait(false) if you’re writing general-purpose library /
>   app-model-agnostic code, and otherwise don’t.

That said, it's a bit of a complex topic, so I'm sure there will be plenty of others here that will disagree. I've written some extremely complex multi-tasked WPF applications, and off the top of my head I can't remember any cases where I've actually needed to use it in application code.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Meaning to say that i don't need the configureawait since i am not updating the UI? Because my code is just doing some processing at the back end and i don't want it to be blocking the UI . while dispatcher is  mainly to update the UI?

Comment: Uh...given that [Stephen Cleary](https://www.amazon.com.au/Concurrency-C-Cookbook-Stephen-Cleary/dp/1449367569) has just rocked up, I think it probably wise for me to back away from this post. Very slowly! :D